# How to execute Microsoft CRM SSIS Package without Full SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am tasked to write a simple Microsoft CRM Online Integration for a client. 
Currently, I am connecting to the clients IBM Database with an ODBC Driver and mapping it to fields in their CRM Online Instance using a Script Component and the SDK.

The problem however is the client does not have SQL Server. They would like to run this package (integration) Weekly. I have been trying to find them an option without them needing to pay thousands of dollars for a SQL Server License.

Is there anyway to run the package weekly without them having SQL Server? They literally will have to pay thousands just to get the dtexec.exe application? 
For clients that don't have SQL Server, how do others integrate with CRM Online without using SSIS?
Is there another easy tool? Or do I need to create my own .NET application that uses the SDK and also connects to their database and do everything in .NET?

Thank you for you advice,
Ian

Answer (score 3):

The customer could create an Azure VM using a SQL Server VM template from the Azure Marketplace. That would provide the customer an on-demand VM that provides a SQL license at a per-minute fee.

You would need to establish connectivity between the VM and the IBM database - presumably via VPN.

Create a PowerShell script to start the VM, send a command to run the appropriate DTEXEC.EXE command line, and stop the VM when complete.

That is how you could get an instance of SSIS without paying for a full license. Depending how long the integration runs the monthly cost is probably less than $25.

Of course, if they already have a Windows Server that can host SQL for the limited purpose of running this integration they can just buy a SQL license for $[3200](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/SQL-Server-2014-Standard-Edition/productID.298540100) and run it locally. Depending on how much it costs them to setup the Azure VM with scripting it might be cheaper for them to just bite-the-bullet and pay for a SQL license.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Yes, if you want to avoid licensing, you will need to write your own application that uses the CRM sdk.

Long answer: I'm not an expert on Microsoft licensing, but there are some third-party tools that we use internally (listed below). Unfortunately you will still not be able to avoid the "thousands of dollars" in licensing. Either you pay for the wheel or you spend at least the same or more reinventing the wheel. :)

http://www.simego.com

http://www.scribesoft.com

http://www.kingswaysoft.com